# NodeJS - From which node version Object.fromEntries() is available?

Tags: node.js

I can't find what's the minimal version of NodeJS that is required to use this method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on a bottom, for node.js it is 12.0.0